# How can i resolve 401 unauthorized error?

Tags: html, mongodb, server, http-status-code-401

I have made a database in Couchdb and to be able to connect remotely I have created a dynamic DNS.  If in postman or in the windows terminal I put the url of the database that is

http://administrator:password@mydomain:5984/database

I get the data in JSON.
[image]

but when i write the same URL in my HTML code, I get the 401 unauthorized error.

[image]
I have written exactly the same URL and I don't understand why i get the 401 error. Can someone help me?

I have configured CORS and Postman doesn't detect any mistake.

Comment: Your question mentions MongoDB, but your question is tagged as CouchDB, and you appear to be connecting to port 5984, the default port for CouchDB.  Which are you using?

Comment: I am using the port 5984

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question is are you using MongoDB or CouchDB? No es claro si estás usando CouchDB (como dice los tags, y tu puerto de 5984) or MongoDB (que dice tu pregunta). ¿Cuál usas?

Comment: Sorry, I am using MongoDB

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected your tags, then.

Comment: Compare your request headers in the browser and in Postman.